# How to delete a file from a folder according size and date

Tags: asp.net, file, directory

Suppose I have 4 files in a folder. 2 files from yesterday (1st file- 1 mb 2nd file- 2mb) and 2 files for today (1st file-5 mb 2nd file- 10 mb).

First, I want to check the date for each file and according to that, the files with minimum size will be deleted from the folder.

In my code I delete all files with minimum size, but I want to delete files which have minimum size day-wise.

Here is my code:

```
private void DeleteFiles()
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\UploadFiles");
    var files = di.GetFiles().GroupBy(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date);

    foreach (var fileGrp in files)
    {
        var maxFile = fileGrp.Max(r => r.Length);
        foreach (FileInfo file in fileGrp.Where(r => r.Length < maxFile))
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
      }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DeleteFiles();
    }
```

This code is running fine, first I group the files according to the date and then delete all files except the largest file. Now what I want is if there are 4 files with the same size for the same date, I want to delete those files and store only one of them in the folder according to it's time. How can I do that?

Comment: in this i want to delete minimum size of files and retain maximum size file per day-wise.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you just order the files by size (smallest to largest) and then by last write time (oldest to newest), and delete until only one is left (either the largest, or if all sizes are the same, the newest):

```
private void DeleteFiles()
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\UploadFiles");
    var files = di.GetFiles().GroupBy(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date);

    foreach (var fileGrp in files)
    {  
        int fileCount = fileGrp.Count();
        foreach (FileInfo f in fileGrp.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a.LastWriteTime))
        {
            if (fileCount > 1)
            {
                f.Delete();
                fileCount--;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it. Re-capture the files after the delete for the current day you are working in and delete all but the newest:

```
private void DeleteFiles() {
    var di = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\UploadFiles");
    var files = di.GetFiles().GroupBy(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date);

    foreach (var fileGrp in files) {
        DateTime currentDay = fileGrp.First().LastWriteTime.Date;
        var maxFile = fileGrp.Max(r => r.Length);
        foreach (FileInfo file in fileGrp.Where(r => r.Length < maxFile)) {
            file.Delete();
        }
        var filesCurrentDay = di.GetFiles()
             .Where(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date == currentDay.Date);
        var maxFileTime = fileGrp.Max(r => r.LastWriteTime.ToFileTimeUtc());
        foreach (FileInfo file in filesCurrentDay 
                   .Where(r => r.LastWriteTime.ToFileTimeUtc() < maxFileTime)) {
           file.Delete();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.DeleteFiles();
    }
}
```

Fixed above to not group by size, originally had a second grouping by size which your requirements do not need.

Comment: Fixed a bunch of issues with my first post.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for multiple files same size, same write time. I can manually create files, run this code, and still end up with 2+ files per day group.

Comment: Also doesn't appear you are doing anything with `maxFileTime`. Typo in that last `foreach`?